# Error when trying to create a C# EF core migration, System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, code-first

I am practicing dependency injection in C# Winforms .Net 6.0. I have separate projects for DAL, BAL, Services, and the WinForms app. At the moment of injecting the dependencies in the Program.cs, everything runs normally, but when I want to create a migration from the console I get this error:

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialLoad
```

Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at MaravilClient.Program.<>c.b__5_1(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in D:\Repos\MaravilClient\MaravilClient\Program.cs:line 36
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__17`1.b__17_1(IServiceProvider p)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetServices[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextTypes()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String name)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here my Program.cs Code:

```
using DAL.DataContext;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Services.ClientActions;
using Services.UserActions;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MaravilClient
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
            ServiceProvider = host.Services;
            var dataContext = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MaravilContext>();
            dataContext.Database.Migrate();
            Application.Run(ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Inicio>());
        }
        public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }
        static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                    services.AddDbContext<MaravilContext>(options =>
                                                   options.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString),ServiceLifetime.Scoped,ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
                    services.AddTransient<IUserActions, UserActions>();
                    services.AddTransient<IClientActions, ClientActions>();
                    services.AddTransient<Inicio>();
                });
        }
      }
}
```

this image shows the reading of the connection string in a MessageBox.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share more details of the error. Like any screen shot or anything.

Comment: Please don't post [screen shots of exceptions](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). Please post them as text.

Comment: From the exception stack trace screenshot, the error is coming from lambda inside `AddDbContext` call, and most likely `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"]` is returning `null`, so make sure your app.config has connection string called "ConnString".

Comment: `public partial class Inicio : Form
    {
        private readonly IUserActions userActionsGlobal;
        public Inicio(IUserActions userActions)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.userActionsGlobal = userActions;   
            MessageBox.Show(userActions.MessageText()+" - "+ ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }`

Comment: `<add connectionString="Data Source = DESKTOP-11DI9SV; Initial Catalog = MaravilDB; Integrated Security = True;" name="ConnString" />`

Comment: I have left the code of the form Inicioand the key of the connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

I have added a json configuration file, to which I set the property of:
Copy to Output Directory=> Copy always.
I also added the connection string to this json file.
The CreateHostBuilder code looks like this:

```
static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
       
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(x=>x.AddJsonFile("appConfig.json"))
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<MaravilContext>(options =>
                                               options.UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLConnection")));
                services.AddTransient<IUserActions, UserActions>();
                services.AddTransient<IClientActions, ClientActions>();
                services.AddTransient<Inicio>();
            });
    }
```

and finally, to execute the migrations from the console/PowerShell it is necessary to specify the csproj address of the migration context like this:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialModification -p ..\DAL\DAL.csproj
```

Thanks to all for your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the related project before run commands (where your dbcontext in ) , Use terminal to set that specific project .After that you can run your migration commands.